# A better word for "obstacle" when referring to a conflicting entity

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

In context, I am looking for a word that refers to something that is in our way and inevitable, a conundrum. The sentence runs "It was there where I survived the greatest obstacle we will ever know. It was there where I survived myself." Obstacle doesn't follow the flow of the rest of the literary style. I want to make the work personable, relatable, and inclusive. I've considered "enemy" and "darkness," but again I want something broad enough to relate to every perception. Just a single word that could convey to anyone that **THING** that we've all had to overcome. Everyone sweats, what makes them sweat?

Comment: We don't usually give writing advice on the site. But have you tried looking for synonyms of "obstacle" in a thesaurus?

Comment: Have you considered albatross? bane?

Comment: A trial is a test you need to pass to continue on your journey, generally speaking.

Comment: @WS2 I have used the thesaurus. It isn't necessarily writing advice. I am unable to express this concept with a single word due to my limited command of the English language, which is why I seek guidance.

Comment: @bookmanu I like bane.

Comment: @Zebrafish are trials inevitable? I guess I might be looking for something a little more metaphysical, a concept that could be personified.

Comment: Thank you all non the less. I will use bane. It conveys a sense of something thats is inevitable and wasnt incited. We all have a bane, whether we like it or not. It could even be ourselves. Bane could also be personified. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Challenge**.

From [Collins](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Challenge):

> (noun) a demanding or stimulating situation, career, object, etc

"Challenge" has slightly more positive connotations than "obstacle" these days.

In your example:

> "It was there where I survived the greatest challenge we will ever know. It was there where I survived myself.

Comment: I like challenge. And it is definitely a positive connotation as of late. But challenges could be seen as avoidable, maybe even by interpretation. Ex. Exercise could be a challenge, while some refuse to label it as such others just avoid the whole thing together. What is not avoidable is the consequences of either extremes of exercise. One must exercise in between "too much" and not at all. Bane was suggested to me. I like it because it expresses something we all hold as an obstacle, yet is unavoidable. Regardless thank you!